# Can't add attribute from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I have two models: `Account` and `Profile`. 
I want render json API with attributes of `Profile` and include there one attribute from `Account`.

profile_serializer.rb

```
class ProfileSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :role

  def role
    #UserAccountSerializer.new(object.role)
    object.account.role
  end
end
```

account_serializer.rb

```
class UserAccountSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :role
end
```

profile.rb

```
class Profile < Grape::API
  desc 'Current user profile'
  get '/', serializer: ProfileSerializer do
    current_user.profile
  end
end
```

accounts_controller.rb

```
class AccountsController < AdminController
    def index
      @accounts = Account.all
    end

    def show
      render json: @account
    end

    def update
      @account = Account.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to accounts_path if @account.update(role: params[:role])
    end
  end
```

account.rb

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile

  enum role: %i[user admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, if: :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end
end
```

profile.rb

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :account
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.bigint "profile_id", null: false
    t.integer "role", default: 0
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_accounts_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["profile_id"], name: "index_accounts_on_profile_id"
end

create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "last_name", null: false
    t.string "first_name", null: false
    t.string "middle_name"
end
```

Grape give me this error: `` undefined method `role' for nil:NilClass ``

Comment: `user` is probably nil in the `Profile`. Do a `Profile.find(id).role` and make sure it exists.

Comment: Where is the link to *user* in your Profile model ?
You should use *account* instead : `object.account.role`

Comment: @PhilippeB. I edit this but error not gone. I don't know but ```account``` not associate with ```Account``` model.

Comment: I understand. Just wrote ```has_one :account, foreign_key :profile_id``` and ```belongs_to :profile, foreign_key :profile_id``` and this two model begun associated beetween itself. Problem was in associate with foreign keys. Thanks for help, guys!